# Python Homework - creating a new list

Tags: python, list

The assignment:

> Write a function called `splitList(myList, option)` that takes, as input, a list and an option, which is either 0 or 1. If the value of the option is 0, the function returns a list consisting of the elements in myList that are negative, and if the value of the option is 1, the function returns a list consisting of the elements in myList that are even.

I know how to determine if a number is even and if a number is negative. I'm struggling with how to return a new list of negative or even numbers based on "option"

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
def splitList(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if (myList[i]%2 == 0):
           newlist.append(myList [i])
    return newlist
```

This program gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment> 
builtins.TypeError: splitList() takes exactly 1 positional argument (4 given)
```

Comment: Define *just crashes*. Is there a traceback?

Comment: You've got nonstandard indentation at `newlist.append(myList[i])`; I don't think this would cause a crash, but maybe?

Comment: How are you calling this?  Did you call it as `splitList(some_list,option)` or `splitList(some_list)`?

Comment: I can see two ways for this to exception out.  Either `myList` isn't a list or it doesn't contain numbers (`['1','2']` contains no numbers -- just strings).  But if your program crashes due to an exception, you will get a traceback that will point out where the error occured and what type of error it was.  We really need to see that traceback to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: This is what it said:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: splitList() takes exactly 1 positional argument (4 given)

Comment: It looks like you aren't passing a list, probably doing `splitList(-1,8,-2,5)` instead of `splitList([-1,8,-2,5])`.  Also note that the assignment asks you to create function `splitList(myList, option)`, but you created `splitList(myList)`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should standardize your indentation: four spaces is Python standard. You can usually set your editor to insert four spaces instead of tabs (don't want to mix tabs with spaces, either).

As to your actual question: try writing three total functions: one that returns all the negative values, one that returns even values, and one that calls the appropriate function based on `option`.

```
def splitlist(myList, option):
    if option == 1:
        return get_even_elements(myList)
    elif option == 0:
        return get_negative_elements(myList)

def get_even_elements(myList):
    pass # Implementation this method here.

def get_negative_elements(myList):
    pass # Implementation this method here.

# Test it out!
alist = [-1, 2, -8, 5]
print splitlist(alist, 0)
print splitlist(alist, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Henry Keiter's comment was correct. Just add one space before `newlist.append(myList [i])` and it works just fine.

Alternatively, if your teacher lets you, you could use tabs instead of spaces to avoid this problem altogether (just make sure you don't use both in the same file).

Comment: At the risk of starting a flame war, please don't recommend tabs over spaces.  Pep8 recommends 4 spaces for python code and since it has become the defacto standard in python style, I would recommend following that suggestion ...

Comment: btw, his code works on my ubuntu box without adding that space, but yes, 4 space-tabs are a good thing

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitList(myList, option):
    return [i for i in myList if i<0] if option==0 else [i for i in myList if i>0]


# test
>>> myList=[2, 3, -1, 4, -7]
>>> splitList(myList, 0)
[-1, -7]
>>> splitList(myList, 1)
[2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: -0.  Just because you *can* put two list comprehensions and one conditional expression on one line doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: readability and reusability first!!! Ninja coding tactics second!!! this might only take one line but damn is it hard to comprehend for a new coder, which means don't do that

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was incorrect, and I really should have tested before I opened my mouth... Doh!!!  Live and learn...

**edit**

your traceback is giving you the answer.  It is reading the list as an args list.  Not sure if there is a super pythonic way to get around it, but you can use named arguments:

```
splitList(myList=yourList)
```

OR

```
splitList(myList=(1,2,3))
```

OR

```
splitList(myList=[1,2,3])
```

But your problem is really probably

```
splitList(1,2,3,4)  # This is not a list as an argument, it is a list literal as your 'args' list
```

Which can be solved with:

```
splitList([1,2,3,4])
```

OR

```
splitList((1,2,3,4))
```

Is this the traceback you get?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    print splitList(aList,1)
TypeError: splitList() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The error is most likely telling you the issue, this would be that the method only takes one argument, but I tried passing in two arguments like your requirements state.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code as-is and I did not get any errors when I passed in a list of positive integers, so I don't know why your program is 'crashing', so I suspect something else is interfering with your debugging.  (Although, as others have said, you really should use the same number of spaces at every indent level.)

Here's what I entered:

```
def splitList(myList):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if (myList[i]%2 == 0):
           newlist.append(myList [i])  # Only 3-space indent here
    return newlist

print splitList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

When I run it:

```
[2, 4]
```

Can you show how you're invoking the method and the exact error message?

Answer (score -6):

**edit**

Can you show the code where you are calling the splitList method?

**this was incorrect**

```
myList [i]
```

is your problem, you can't have a space in there.  python is VERY VERY VERY strict about syntax

since people seemed to think they should downvote me, let me explain:

by having that space, you effectively said myList (which is a list), and [i], which is a list literal with the value of 'i' at index 0....

so you are passing two variables (one actual variable and one literal) into the append method, NOT separated by a comma, which will not work.

Comment: You can have a space there -- Although it is unusual.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect.  Just try it out and see.  `a = range(10); a [2]`

Comment: or rather self.kickAss(self)